# Applying SUPEE-6788, it removes static block

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-6788

Today I applied patch SUPEE-6788, and I noticed that the static block on my home page disappeared.

I have checked in admin side, i have used `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="10"..` and `{{block type="responsivebannerslider/index" name="responsivebannerslider_index" .`.

Similarly i have used so many block in my Magento sites.

I have read on google and find the solution to manually add these blocks in System -> Permissions -> Blocks.

Ok, I have manually added two "catalog/product_list" and "responsivebannerslider/index", and it is working fine.

But my problem is, i don't know how many block i have added in my magento sites. It is not possible for me to manually add these block in ***System -> Permissions -> Blocks.***

**How to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox

This tool box will help ypu , but do a through research before using it , i have no used it (and i never use these scripts as well ) but since you dont want to go through the pain of whitelisting every block

```
php -f fixSUPEE6788.php -- fixWhitelists
```

Might do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this addon for Magerun: https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons#find-non-whitelisted-varsblocks-to-be-compatible-with-supee-6788-and-magento-1922 to find all used custom blocks and variables. See also your duplicated post on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33433109/622945